# Change my horizontal submenu to vertical drop-down

Tags: drop-down-menu, html5boilerplate

I want to change my horizontal submenu to a drop-down style menu. Here is my CSS:

```
#menubar ul{
    height:48px;
    clear:both;
}
#menubar li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    height:48px;
    margin-top:11px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}
#menubar a{
    line-height:48px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:800;
    color:#4A4A4A;
}
#menubar a:hover{
    color:#000;
}
#menubar li:last-child{
    border-right: 0 none;
}
ul.children{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
#menubar li:hover > ul {
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
}
ul.children li{
    width:200px;
    position:static;
    float:none;
    display: block;
    margin:-10px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#fff;
    clear:both;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 9px #a6d19c;
    border:1px solid #a6d19c;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    border-top:none;
    margin-left:0;
}
#menubar ul.children a{
    float:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

I've tried eliminating the blocks and inline displays, but to no avail. I'm used to applying my CSS to elements like:

```
#access ul li li {}
```

and don't really understand the .children class.

Any help to make this a drop-down menu is appreciated. :)

Comment: I think what you have is mostly there. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uPJq/) with your CSS and assumed some markup.

Comment: Thanks, Don!! This solved the problem. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, your CSS works, you would just need a UL that is a child of one of the main LIs, marked with `class="children"` e.g.

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Parent menu</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="">Child menu items</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child menu items 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```